# Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.PropertyPath'

Tags: c#

I'm very new in C# and programming, trying to study by Head First C# book.
Have re-writed the code several times, but still getting the error message:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Windows.PropertyPath'

Would be very appreciated for help :)

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
namespace Save_The_Humans
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddEnemy();
        }
        private void AddEnemy()
        {
            ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
            enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), 
                random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight-100),"(Canvas.Top)");
            playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
        }
        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);//THIS IS A PROBLEMATIC LINE, the "propertyToAnimate" is underlined.
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not providing the correct argument type to the method: the second parameter is of type `PropertyPath` while you're providing an object of type `string`.

The solution is as simple as :

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
```

Source : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672995(v=vs.95).aspx#Anchor_3)

Comment: Thanks, @user3185569 ! It looks like resolved but now getting message

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,new PropertyPath("propertyToAnimate")); then trying to run. Some suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Slava It should be `new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate)` without the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this and try

```
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
```

Since the second argument is PropertyPath type not string

Comment: Thanks, @Sreemat ! It looks like resolved but now getting message Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,new PropertyPath("propertyToAnimate")); then trying to run. Some suggestion? Thanks a lot! –

Comment: Can't get you understand @Slava

Comment: Post the value in propertyToAnimate here @Slava

Comment: Don't pass as string new PropertyPath("propertyToAnimate") Pass it as argument new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate) @Slava

Comment: all that I've found is: Property Value, Type: SystemInvalidOperationExeption
Sorry for so confused explanation, I'm very beginner in C#, started learning with a Head First Book. May be I should learn in a regular way, not by re-writing somebody else code?

Comment: yes,getting Additional information: Must specify TargetProperty for 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'.
using new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate) without the double quotes leads to error in line 27-28..

Comment: Are you sure you used this whole code Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));? @Slava

Comment: No not available @Slava